# Reuse browser window when pressting restart button when debugging ASP.NET application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio and use this button

[image: reload button]

I would like to have the browser reused (never closed).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the **restart** button, VS will always open a new browser and close the old browser at the same time by default.

And there is no such function to reuse the same brower directly.

**As a suggestion**, you can try solution to get close to it:

**1)** uncheck the option `Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET(chrome,Edge and IE)` under `Tools`->`Options`->`Debugging`->`General`.

uncheck option `Stop debugger when browser window is closed,close browser when debugging stop` under `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions`->`Web Projects`.

**2)** When you restart your web project by clicking the icon, it will not close your previous browser and will open a new browser. At this time, close the new browser immediately and refresh the previous browser.

This will be more like using the old browser.